# MongoDB and Aggregation Framework Pipeline Stages

Tags: mongodb

I have a doubt like,i am using mongodb aggregation framework but i have multiple stages of $lookup in the pipeline does it going to affect the performance.Is there any limitation on number of stages in the aggregation pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

There is no limitation on the number of stages in a pipeline.  However, there are result size and memory limitations, refer to the [online doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/).  `$lookup` doesn't, at least for now, take advantage of indexes.  The more data and stages you have, the more time mongo engines needs to process.